# How to implement interface with delegate quickly in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, delegates, code-generation

I see only two quick options for delegation.

One is `Source -> Generate Delegate Methods`. This way Eclipse implements all (or selected) methods of delegate member as delegate methods.

Another one is `Source -> Override/Implement Methods`. This way Eclipse will implement all (or selected) methods of interface as stub methods.

Both options are incomplete. First one generates too much methods (may generate ones which is not in interface). Second one does not generate good methods, only stubs.

Is it possible to combine both, i.e. generate all methods for delegate member, but filtered by interface?

Comment: Weird thing. Once, I got a hint for fixing an issue "Implement using member...". But I cannot get it to appear again. I came here googling for it.